# How to delete relationship lines?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I imported this building, and there are all these relationship lines in it. How do I delete the relationship info? I know how to hide the lines, but assuming they're 'junk', how do I get rid of them?

Comment: Not sure if I would call parenting "junk".  What does the hierarchy look like, is there a common parent?

Answer (score 4):

Select objects, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. Select *Clear Parents and Keep Transform*, if you want to keep their current positions.